# Initialize Maps API in module pattern

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to initialize Google Maps API in module pattern but all I get are the errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

and

```
Uncaught InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function
```

gmap.js:

```
var map,
    mapsAPI = (function() {
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapAddress'), {
                center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                zoom: 8,
                scrollwheel: false
            });
        }

        function init() {
            mapsAPI.initMap();
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', init());
    }());
```

On the html I am loading in this order (note that I removed my API Key from this example):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY=initMap"
        async defer></script>

<script src="scripts/gmap.js"></script>
```

If I put the initMap() on Global scope the map works but I am trying to avoid using Global variables.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at the script src link for the google maps API. Here's the example link given in [the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#The_Hello_World_of_Google_Maps_v3):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
  key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

The last querystring param is `callback=initMap`.

The google maps script at some point tries to call the callback function it has been given by this param. However, it will only be able to access this `initMap` function if it is on the global scope.

Not polluting the global scope is certainly good practice in general, but I wouldn't worry about it when it's just one function (you can still keep your other variables/functions hidden), and you have a good reason.

Answer (score -2):

[Register for a new key](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_backend,geocoding_backend,directions_backend,distance_matrix_backend,elevation_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE&reusekey=true&pli=1) 
and copy it. Use this link in your JavaScript file: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap`
Use your API key in the above URL.